# SSD optimization?

Tags: ssd

I'm a complete newbie and just installed elementary loki. I followed post installation tutorial and did:

- `sudo mv -v /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim /fstrim` 
  (to disable the weekly trim)
- `sudo -i scratch-text-editor /etc/rc.local` (to add the TRIM command `fstrim` for every automatically mounted EXT4 partition on your SSD)

Is that ok?

And another question. is it safe to use TLP and how I stop the computer going to sleep when I'm watching movies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing trim every boot or weekly won't make a huge difference unless you are constantly writing lots of data. Anyway, make sure your ssd supports it:

> Execute `lsblk -D` from a terminal and check the values of `DISC-GRAN` and `DISC-MAX`. Non zero values indicate trim support.

TLP is safe and it's also recommended to use it instead of `laptop-mode-tools`. So you can install it safely with `sudo apt install tlp`

Your laptop shouldn't go to sleep if you are watching a movie in fullscreen mode. You can go into fullscreen mode if you double click on the video if you are using the elementary video app.

You can also disable automatic sleep if you want. Just go to `System Settings > Power`. And in there set `Turn off display when inactive for:` and `Sleep when inactive for:` to `Never`.

---

[SSD Cite](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives#TRIM)

Comment: How do I revert the trim setting back to how it was by default?

Comment: Remove TRIM command from /etc/rc.local and then reverse the mv command sudo mv -v /fstrim /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim